# Why is the direction not changing here for the first function call?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It seems like image(0) and image(1) are the same in this array, but i can't figure out why this behaviour occurs.
In the console it showed me this

> i=5; div class="five" id="slides"
>
> i=0; div class="one" id="slides"
>
> i=1; div class="one" id="slides"

---

Link to my [pen](http://codepen.io/Eike-K/pen/zxLBNX)

```
var i = 0;
var image = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var slider = document.getElementById("slides");
function changeBG(direction) {
  if(direction == "up"){
    if(i != 5) {
        slider.className = image[i];
        console.log(i, slider);
      i++;
    }
    else {
      i = 0;
      slider.className = image[i];
      console.log(i, slider);
      i++;
    }
  }
  else {
    if(i != -1) {
        slider.className = image[i];
        console.log(i, slider);
      i--;
    }
    else {
      i = 4;
      slider.className = image[i];
      console.log(i, slider);
      i--;
    }
  }
  console.log(direction);
}
```

---

Edit: logging the array showed this

> Array [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ]

---

Now after logging the direction aswell I found out that when changing directions
e.g. from '`up'` to `'down'` `i` will still increase and not go down for the first call of changeBG()
is anybody able to explain this?

Comment: @OP if you edited the question.Don't forgot to mention it in update :-p
You created a confusion here.

Comment: sorry for the downvotes you got :)

Comment: It's fine you just created a confusion that's a problem :-) And +1 for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing:

```
else {
  i = 0;
  slider.className = image[i];
  i++;//================================> you missed it
  console.log(i, slider);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that direction is "up":

when `i` is 0, then you set the className to the first element of the array *before* incrementing `i`, and *then* you log the className and the newly incremented i (so `i` is 1 at this point).

when `i` is 4, you set it to zero, set className to the first element of the array, and *do not* increment `i` before logging it, so it will show `i` == 0

Answer (score 1):

For the right console.log must be before increase or decrease of i

```
console.log(i, slider);
i++;
```

or
     console.log(i, image[i]);

Comment: sorry for that i didn't see that question is edited.